# How to do permission-based UI display

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, datatables

**UPDATE**-
I have altered the question based on new information:

We have a small application that is returning Search results in a grid. There is only one controller action because this is all the application does. However, there are some pieces of data that we want hidden based on user permissions. For instance, based on a users permission, I hide the StockSource column in HTML like this:

```
<th>Name</th>
@if (Model.UserCanSeeThis)
{ 
    <th>StockSource</th>
}
<th>SomeOtherColumn</th>
```

Then in this js code we use [DataTables](http://datatables.net/index) to build a display grid:

```
  $('#grdSearch').dataTable( {
        "bProcessing": true,
        "sAjaxSource": uri,
        "fnServerData": function(sSource, aoData, fnCallback, oSettings) {
            oSettings.jqXHR = $.ajax(
                {
                    type: "POST",
                    url: sSource,
                    data: JSON.stringify(BuildSearchParams()),
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (typeof data["error"] == "undefined") {
                            fnCallback(data);
                        } else {
                            alert(data["error"]);
                        }
                    }
                });
        },
        "aoColumns": [
            { "mData": "Name" },
            { "mData": "StockSource" },
            { "mData": "SomeOtherColumn" }
        ]});
```

The problem is I can't set "StockSource" to invisible, because if the user didn't have permission, there isn't a StockSource column to set to null. Any ideas how to control this?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way I could think of is, you could create an inline script to handle the aoColumns on your view page.

```
<script>
//Preload with the first column since you know it will always be there
var includedColumns = [{ "mData": "Name" }];
@if (Model.UserCanSeeThis)
{ 
    //Add stock source when the user can see
    includedColumns.push({ "mData": "StockSource" });
}
//Add additional columns
includedColumns.push({ "mData": "SomeOtherColumn" });
</script>
```

Then you can just use the variable

```
$('#grdSearch').dataTable( {
        "bProcessing": true,
        "sAjaxSource": uri,
        "fnServerData": function(sSource, aoData, fnCallback, oSettings) {
            oSettings.jqXHR = $.ajax(
                {
                    type: "POST",
                    url: sSource,
                    data: JSON.stringify(BuildSearchParams()),
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (typeof data["error"] == "undefined") {
                            fnCallback(data);
                        } else {
                            alert(data["error"]);
                        }
                    }
                });
        },
        "aoColumns": includedColumns });
```

Comment: Ended up doing something very similar to this. Thanks Bret!

Answer (score 1):

i would still do it on the server side. just don't set the variable StockSource

and js would look like

```
if (data != null) {
    /* Get data for the given row */
    out = "<table cellpadding='5' cellspacing='0' border='0' style='padding-left:50px;'>";
    out += "<tr><td>Name:</td><td>" + data["Name"] + "</td></tr>";
    if (data["StockSource"])
            out += "<tr><td>Stock Source:</td><td>" + data["StockSource"] + "</td></tr>";
    out += "</table>";
}
```

Comment: I like that. Unfortunately, I found that the real place I need to control is the one I changed my question to above where "aoColumns" is being built. My bad. Any ideas there?

Answer (score 1):

As you are using MVC I would suggest you pass a model back to a view creating a table.  That way you can create the columns required in a cleaner way than you are doing it at the moment as your current table generation code is not easily maintainable.

In your view you could simply do a check if the column is needed and render it and if not needed then don't render it.

Comment: You are right, and that's typically how I would do it, but in this case all the calls are made directly to a WebAPI from the js, so the only controller action being used is the one rendering the search page initially.